# showing $\sqrt{n}$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, real-numbers

I want to show that $a_{n} = \sqrt{n}$ is not a bounded sequence.

Definition: We say that a sequence is bounded if it is bounded above and below. A sequence $a_{n}$ is bounded above if there exists $C$ such that, for all $n$, $a_{n} \leq C$. A sequence $a_{n}$ is bounded below if there exists $C$ such that, for all $n$, $a_{n} \geq C$.

Well clearly, our sequence is bounded below by $0$. So we need to show it is not bounded above.

Proof:

We need to show that for every $C$, there exists an $n$ such that $a_{n} > C$. Observing that for every $C \geq  0, \sqrt{C^{2}} = C$. Suppose that $ n > C^{2}$ then we have $\sqrt{n} > C$

Comment: Well, you need to show that $n>C^2$ implies $\sqrt{n}>C$.

Comment: You don't have to choose C. You need to prove that for every C exists $n$ (as you said at the start)

Comment: Thanks all. I've edited it based on the first comment I saw from jlammy, is this now correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\sqrt n\le u$. But then $n=(\lfloor u\rfloor+1)^2$ is such that $\sqrt n>u$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hi, this makes sense thank you. If I wanted to directly apply the definition, for practice, does my current attempt in my post work? Thanks.

Comment: @learningmathematics: it is the same.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$ (a_n) $ is bounded $ \iff $

$$(\exists m,M\in \Bbb R)\;: $$
$$ \;(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\; m\le a_n\le M$$

$$\iff (\exists M\ge 0)\; : $$
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\; 0\le |a_n|\le M$$

$$\implies (\forall n\in \Bbb N)\; 0\le a_n^2\le M^2$$

$$\implies (a_n^2) \text{ is bounded}$$

If $ a_n=\sqrt{n} $ then $ a_n^2=n $ and $ (a_n^2)$ is not bounded because for any $ C\ge 0 $, $ n=\lfloor C \rfloor +2>C $.